# Displacement and subdivisions slowing down my blender a lot

Tags: subdivision-surface

I'm incredibly new to blender and I'm trying to generate some good looking renders of 3D parts designed in Autodesk Inventor. I imported the parts as OBJs and have applied materials to them etc. I have a displacement map for a textured rubber part and following a tutorial (im that new) generated a subdivision surface and used a displacement map for the material. My blender is now running incredibly slow and when i tried to do the same thing for another part staight up crashed. My PC is pretty beefy (cpu - 5950x, gpu 3090 and 64gb of ram) and so I'm surprised that this had such an effect. Is there something obvious i could be doing wrong?

Comment: What level did you set your subdiv modifier to? - I rarely go above 2 and wouldn't want to use higher than 3.

Comment: that would probably be it then, mine are set up at 5. I'll give that a go, thanks

Comment: Every time you increase the level by one you double the number of vertices on your object! How many verts does it show on the bottom Status bar?